# Reconnection to Redis after reboot

Tags: redis, fault-tolerance, jedis

I've a bunch long running processes that connect to a Redis server (using Jedis). Everything works fine as long as I don't reboot the machine running Redis or restart the Redis server. As soon as I reboot or restart the connection is lost. Is there a standard way of dealing with this use case in Redis/Jedis or do I need to put this logic in all my clients myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Redis Failure/Connection Dropped**
In this case, redis either goes down or drops the connection while your process remains active. To ensure the process gets a good connection, use `testOnBorrow=true` in jedis connection/pool config. Jedis will test each connection with 'PING' before using it; if redis does not respond, the connection is discarded and it will try another connection.

**Machine Reboot/Restart (not redis)**
If the application node fails or reboots, your "processes" should be configured to restart automatically upon reboot (if that's the behavior you desire), or someone starts it manually. In either case, I'd expect your process to create and initialize a new jedis connection before it does any real work...so what else do you need beyond that?

Comment: By "your process creates and initializes a new jedis connection before it does any real work, right?" you mean if the Redis client process(es) get a new resource from the RedisPool everytime they want to do something on Redis?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If the client node restarts, the jedis pool will automatically be reinitialized, your process must be doing that part already, right?

Comment: No the client node doesn't restart. The Redis server restarts because of a hard reboot of the Redis physical node. Will the JedisPool (on the client side) still reinitialize ?

Comment: We've tested jedis pool in this scenario; it reconnects after redis recovers, no problems. We use `testOnBorrow=true`, the remaining settings are default.